# How do I handle different timezones between app and server data in Swift ios programming?

Tags: ios, iphone, datetime, timezone

I am not sure this has been answered before. 
I need to know if its possible to handle two different timezones that are not +0000.

What I mean is that my iphone app calls data from the server such creation date and time of certain objects. But the dates and time is in danish time, meaning timezone the date was created in is something like +0100

But the iphone app thinks the initial timezone is +0000 of course, and if I use dateformatter to set the timezone, it adds an hour to the initial datetime which is incorrect.

Is there a sensible way to handle timezones in Swift, or will I have to subtract an hour manually each time I convert from danish time to whatever is on the phone of the user?

Comment: Change both server and app timezone to GMT / timestamp, done, easy to store, compare, calculate, reverse...etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ask Web Service developer if dates which are returning, are those in GMT or not? If not, then ask them to store dates in GMT only.

When api returns data, convert your date to your desired format.

I did this in swift 2.2. Created a String extension.

```
extension String {
func getFormattedDate(currentFormat : String,convertFormat : String) -> String {
    let dateStr = self
    let dateFormate = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormate.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
    dateFormate.dateFormat = currentFormat
    if let date = dateFormate.dateFromString(dateStr) {
        dateFormate.dateFormat = convertFormat
        dateFormate.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
        return dateFormate.stringFromDate(date)
    }
    return ""
}

func getFormattedDateForDefaultTimeZone(currentFormat : String,convertFormat : String) -> String {
    let dateStr = self
    let dateFormate = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormate.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    dateFormate.dateFormat = currentFormat
    if let date = dateFormate.dateFromString(dateStr) {
        dateFormate.dateFormat = convertFormat
        dateFormate.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
        return dateFormate.stringFromDate(date)
    }
    return ""
}
}
```

Use like below:

```
let dateStr = btnDate.currentTitle!.getFormattedDate("dd/MMM/yyyy", convertFormat: "dd-MM-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you need to ask the server side to use GMT +00 so that if they will want to work with some other country it will work fine for everyone..

Or, another way is to store time in Timestamp. And it will be automatically GMT +00

And then the system will handle it for you considering user's time zone on the phone.

Hope it helps